# Is it possible to frame a group of cells?

Tags: cells

Is it possible to put a frame around a group of cells (e.g. a numbered list)?

My problem is, that if I select the cell group and then click frame on the writing assistant, then it puts a frame around each cell in stead of one frame around all the cells in the marked group.

Merging the cells into one does not work either, as that removes the item numbers in lists.

Comment: Perhaps you can add some (mockup) screenshot to show what you want to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by "(...) and then frame that (...)"? Did you use the "Writing assistent" do set a frame around your grouped cell?

Comment: I want to put a frame around a group of cells. If I do that by 'Frame' on the writing assistant, then it puts a separate frame around each cell in the group, where I would have liked one frame around the entire group.

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: [(6264)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6264/121) Is that the look you want to achieve?

Comment: Since my comment was never answered I am taking this question as abandoned and closing it in favor of a newer question.