# Framing a combination of cells in the notebook

Tags: notebooks

In my notebook, I have the following cells, which I tried to put around a single frame with a light blue background color.

[image]

After entering the cells, I selected all four, then clicked the frame button in the Writing Assistant palette. Unfortunately, I did not get a single frame.

Can some suggest how I can get just a single frame around all four cells? The centered cells are from the Writing Assistant, Math Cells, Centered Math Cell.

**They do not match what I want:**

Perhaps I should ask how can put all of my writing in one cell.

**Thank you, Mr. Wizard:**

I selected the four cells, then used Mr. Wizard's Frame Multiple Cells button, which was created by his code, and here is the result:

[image]

I added the red color to the word definition after using Mr. Wizard's button.

**Using the Writing Assistant Pallete:**

It turns out that if I select my four cells, then click on the Merge Cells icon on the Writing Assistant tablet, it's done! Then use the Writing Assistant tablet to add a frame and color the background.

Comment: I wonder if the solution proposed here would work for you: [Automatically use InputOnly style](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6264/automatically-use-inputonly-style). A similar question was asked here as well: [Is it possible to frame a group of cells?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29475/is-it-possible-to-frame-a-group-of-cells).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question is closely related to [Automatically use InputOnly style](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6264/automatically-use-inputonly-style) and it can also be done with [`CellFrame`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellFrame.html) and [`CellMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellMargins.html).  Here is a [`Button`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html) to automate the process.

```
Button["Frame Multiple Cells",
  With[{cells = Cells[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]]]},
   MapThread[
    Function[{frame, pos},
     MapAt[
      SetOptions[#,
        CellMargins -> {{66, 10}, {0, 0}},
        CellFrame   -> {{2, 2}, frame},
        Background  -> LightBlue] &,
      cells,
      pos
     ]
    ],
    {{{0, 2}, {0, 0}, {2, 0}}, {1, 2 ;; -2, -1}}
   ]
  ]
] // CreatePalette
```

[image]

Notes:

- Setting a Background color affects the spacing of the cells; without it they squeeze together.
- To keep the frame continuous to the Output cell I had to disable automatic grouping.

Comment: Wow! It worked beautifully. See my update to my original post.

Comment: Automatic grouping? Not sure what that is or if its disabling will affect what I normally do?

Comment: This is so good, I'd like to add it to my Palettes menu or my writing assistant. Is that possible?

Comment: Does disabling automatic grouping slow down printing of the notebook?

Comment: Note that setting the option `CellGroupingRules -> "NormalGrouping"` (in the button) overrides the automatic grouping so that the frame is continuous.

Comment: @David (1) Grouping can be controlled via the menu **Cell** > **Grouping**.  Normally output cells are grouped with input cells automatically, as one example.  These groups are indented differently therefore the frame has step or jump in it.  As Michael just posted turning off grouping can be added to the button if that is desired.  (2) Yes, at least to the first.  Try the menu **File** > **Install...** and select Palette.  Theoretically you could also modify (a copy of) the built-in palettes but I don't think I've ever actually done that.  (3) I rarely print Notebooks but I don't think so.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for that.  I didn't attempt it as I wasn't sure it was desired.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard et al, I just realized that the Writing Assistant allows me to group cells together. I selected the four cells, opened the Writing Assistant palette, then under Cell Modifications, clicked Merge Cells button. Done. I was then able to Frame and provide Background Color using the Writing Assistant. I can't believe I didn't see the Merge Cells tool on the Writing Assistant earlier. But thanks for the wonderful help.

Comment: @David Too often we forget to include the simple answers.  In this case I *assumed* that you were aware of merging cells and did not want that.  Sorry.  Nevertheless there may be reasons to keep the individual cells.  As shown in my answer they can be of different types.  Also cell icons and numbering should be preserved, though I didn't actually test that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. No worries Mr. Wizard. Your help is greatly appreciated and you have helped me learn a lot of things.