# How to expand and collapse multiple cells inside a frame while keeping all in a single frame

Tags: notebooks, cells

I am trying to create a framed cell around cells that collapse and expand.  [Mr. Wizard's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88353) below almost does it, however, when the cells are collapsed I lose the lower frame border. I'd like to keep it. Here is his code. I'm having trouble fixing this. Can someone help?

```
Button["Frame Multiple Cells",
  With[{cells = Cells[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]]]},
   MapThread[
    Function[{frame, pos},
     MapAt[
      SetOptions[#,
        CellMargins -> {{66, 10}, {0, 0}},
        CellFrame   -> {{2, 2}, frame},
        Background  -> LightBlue] &,
      cells,
      pos
     ]
    ],
    {{{0, 2}, {0, 0}, {2, 0}}, {1, 2 ;; -2, -1}}
   ]
  ]
] // CreatePalette
```

Update with GIF to explain:
[image]

Comment: I rephrased this question to include the exact functionality I am looking for.

Comment: The frame should be only around the section group etc, or you want to create them manually?

Comment: @Kuba When I have a group of cells I see a frame surrounding the entire group.  But when I collapse the cells so that I only see the first cell, I see a frame that only surrounds the left, top and right.  The bottom no longer has the frame.  I'm looking for a solution that keeps the frame around all the content whether the group is closed (to show only the first cell) or open (showing all cells in the group).  I can make an animated gif if this doesn't describe it to your satisfaction.

Comment: And yes.  I am using manual grouping turned on.

Comment: In trying to alter the code, but it seems the way it is written I can't do this without putting in some sort of conditional somewhere.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this as I don't know of a way that Mathematica can tell me if a group is currently open or closed programmatically.

Comment: I updated the question with an animated gif to illustrate the question.

Comment: Does this framing work for you well? When I use Mr. Wizard's method Input cells that are grouped with Output have additional indenting so the frame isn't straight :/

Comment: @Kuba It works for me so long as I treat it as a group shown in the gif above.  I'm actually collapsing all cell into the first cell.  So its not actually a group.  But it works.  There is no indentation which is nice, but I can't seem to get the frame on the bottom to stay.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain, may I ask you to share the snippet for making buttons for Cells 'Background' colors (I can see four of them in the upper left corner of the GIF :-)?

Comment: Sure you can email me at michaelmccain@mac.com

Comment: @MichaelMcCain, I've sent an email from garej{a}mail.ru